# How to Convert this Greasemonkey code to JavaScript for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, greasemonkey, android-webview, userscripts

I am trying to load a page and then run a javascript code on it, I found a Greasemonkey script that does the same, but I am having problems implementing the same thing in android, probably because I don't know anything about javascript.

This is the Greasemonkey script; it's supposed to a give a new link:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function ()
{   
    var link = document.evaluate("//div[@class='dl_startlink']/div/a[contains(@href,'"+window.location.href.match(/\?(.*)$/)[1]+"')]", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    if( !link.snapshotLength )
        return;     
    location.href = link.snapshotItem(0).href;      

}, false);
```

and this is how I want to run it:

```
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("webview loaded");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:/*...........Javascript code here........*/");

           }
```

Any ideas on how I get that link and load that page in the webview?
EDIT: Another version does the same thing.

```
var candidates = document.evaluate("//*[@class = 'dl_startlink']/div", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
 if( !candidates.snapshotLength ) 
return;
//The DIV with the highest zIndex has the *real* link; the rest are useless.
- var maxDiv = candidates.snapshotItem(0);
- for( var i = 1; i < candidates.snapshotLength; i++ )
- if( maxDiv.style.zIndex < candidates.snapshotItem(i).style.zIndex )
- maxDiv = candidates.snapshotItem(i);
- location.href = maxDiv.children[0].href;
```

Comment: Have you tried just minify that code (inside a function), replace spaces with `%20` and put it into link?

Comment: @kirilloid no, i have no idea how that would work, as far as i know, this code is specific to user scripts, for ex document.evaluate only works for firefox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's only simple Xpath query, which may be rewritten as CSS selector.

Also I decided to replace `window.location.href.match(/\?(.*)$/)[1]`. If my version will not work, replace first 2 lines with `var query = window.location.href.match(/\?(.*)$/)[1];`.

Actually, maybe even `var query = window.location.search.replace(/^\?/,'')` is enough.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function ()
{   
    var l = window.location;
    var query = l.search ? (l.search.replace(/^\?/,'') + l.hash) : ""

    var link = document.querySelector("div.dl_startlink > div > a[href='" + query + "']");
    if (!link) return;
    l.href = link.href;
}, false);
```

New code for Android:

```
var candidates = document.querySelector("div.dl_startlink > div");
if( !candidates.length) 
    return;
//The DIV with the highest zIndex has the *real* link; the rest are useless.
var maxDiv = candidates[0];
for( var i = 1; i < candidates.length; i++ )
    if( maxDiv.style.zIndex < candidates[i].style.zIndex )
        maxDiv = candidates[i];
location.href = maxDiv.children[0].href;
```

Compacted version:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.addEventListener('load',function(){var%20candidates=document.querySelector('div.dl_startlink>div');if(!candidates.length)return;var maxDiv=candidates[0];for(var%20i=1;i<candidates.length;i++)if(maxDiv.style.zIndex<candidates[i].style.zIndex)maxDiv=candidates[i];location.href=maxDiv.children[0].href;},false)");
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, but how do i run this in the webview, the only way i can think of is to put this code in a html or js file and load that file, but that is resulting in an infinite loop of loading the file rather than the injection..??

Comment: You described that in your question! `webView.loadUrl("javascript:/*one-lined js code here*/");` Opening `javascript:`-URL doesn't reload the page. Also: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Comment: @kirillorid sorry about that i just got confused for a moment, but this code does have something wrong, it didn't do anything and nothing in the logs either, i have added another version on the script which does the same thing but with a older code and a different method, maybe that could give you any insights..

Comment: SyntaxError: return not in function. That code should be inside function as well as in first version.

Comment: @kirillorid i tried doing something like this stackoverflow.com/questions/5649111/… I am still getting the PHRASE ERROR AT UNDEFINED 1. also the double quotes seemingly mark the end of javascript, how do i escape those, "\\" doesn't work, Could you maybe edit the code and place it inside a function..?